# When removing a row from observableArray, the update function of the custom bindings are not getting called [jsfiddle link]

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

So I have a collection that I loop through to display some data.  There's a remove button next to each row to remove a given row's $data from the observableArray collection.  It removes it fine, but here's the problem.  Some of the input fields on each row have a custom binding that I created to do some validation.  As the user is interacting with the form, the update event of the custom binding gets fired as it should.  But when the user removes a row, the update event does NOT fire!

This completely messes up the state of my validation.  Does anyone know what's going on here?

Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emirhosseini/SCxdB/2/) for this issue.

**Update**: Also, in situations where the update event does get called in result of a change, the order in which the events get called are problematic.  If I remove an element, the update event gets called first due to some update to an observable at which point the element itself is still in the DOM.  So I have no way of knowing inside the update event whether or not the element that is being updated still exists in the DOM or not!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example the binding is only on the obervable item not on the array. Add your binding to the observableArray - append to the foreach binding in your example

```
<div data-bind="foreach: firstNames, validators:true">
    <input type="text" data-bind="value: firstname, validators:true" />
    <span data-bind="text: firstname"></span>
    <input type="button" value="remove" data-bind="click: $root.deleteRow" /><br />
</div>
```

greetings @all